# Encapsulate other Apps in .Net MDI

Tags: .net, encapsulation, mdi

Is it possible to encapsulate other windows apps in a .Net MDI form? The source code is not available for these apps... there's a set of programs we use that would be nice to have all wrapped into one app...

An easy example would be maybe having a .net mdi form app that has a calculator button. When its clicked, it opens the windows calc.exe in an mdi form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reliable way of doing it that I know of. It all depends on what this other app is doing with its windows.

We tried something similar quiet some time ago. We had some success with some apps, for some other apps it just did not work, but even for those where it did work it was not too stable.